# Replacing performSelectorInBackground with GCD

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

In my iOS app I'm running a computationally intensive task on a background thread like this:

```
// f is called on the main thread
- (void) f {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doCalcs) withObject:nil]; 
}

- (void) doCalcs {
    int r = expensiveFunction();
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayResults:) withObject:@(r) waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

**How can I use GCD to run an expensive calculation such that it doesn't block the main thread?**

I've looked at `dispatch_async` and some options for the GCD queue choice but I'm too new to GCD to feel like I understand it sufficiently.

Comment: What did you try after looking at `dispatch_async` ?

Comment: @Wain just reading about the various queue choices and trying to understand when GCD would run something on a background thread or perhaps asynchronously on the main thread.

Comment: so you found the way to get the main queue, the global queue (for a priority) and a specifically created queue ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use dispatch_async like suggested.

For example:

```
    // Create a Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) queue to process data in a background thread.
dispatch_queue_t myprocess_queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);

// Start the thread 

dispatch_async(myprocess_queue, ^{
    // place your calculation code here that you want run in the background thread.

    // all the UI work is done in the main thread, so if you need to update the UI, you will need to create another dispatch_async, this time on the main queue.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    // Any UI update code goes here like progress bars

    });  // end of main queue code block
}); // end of your big process.
// finally close the dispatch queue
dispatch_release(myprocess_queue);
```

That's the general gist of it, hope that helps.

Comment: or you can use `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)` (or pick another priority if you prefer) instead of creating your own queue.

Comment: You can safely delete that last line since you don't need to handle memory management for that queue yourself.
See this note in Apple's documentation:
"You do not need to retain or release any of the global dispatch queues, including the concurrent dispatch queues or the main dispatch queue. Any attempts to retain or release the queues are ignored."